# MS Access VBA Substitution Cipher Encrypt/Decrypt

Tags: ms-access, encryption, vba

Could anyone suggest please how I can achieve a substitution cipher style; encrypt and decrypt function in VBA.  I appreciate hashing is considered the better way but I need reversible encryption. Many Thanks.

Comment: Don't you already have one that [you tried to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534659/vba-ms-access-substitution-cipher)?

Comment: @Deanna As Jean said I did post it earlier, but ignored the rules of stack overflow im sorry to say, this way is better as people are offering answers and others may be able to find it in the future through a google search etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks for all the answers provided in reference to my question, it's good to see there are different approaches, this is one I coded yesterday morning. It allows a different cipher keyword/phrase to be used for both Upper & Lowercase letters, I have used 'Zebras' in this example, it also runs a second pass with the ROT13 cipher. Encryption method:

```
Public Function Encrypt(strvalue As String) As String

Const LowerAlpha    As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const LowerSub      As String = "zebrascdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy" 'zebras
Const UpperAlpha    As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Const UpperSub      As String = "ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY" 'ZEBRAS

Dim lngi            As Long
Dim lngE            As Long
Dim strEncrypt      As String
Dim strLetter       As String

If strvalue & "" = "" Then Exit Function

For lngi = 1 To Len(strvalue)

    strLetter = Mid(strvalue, lngi, 1)

    Select Case Asc(strLetter)

        Case 65 To 90 'Uppercase
            'Find position in alpha string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(UpperAlpha)
                If Mid(UpperAlpha, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo USub
            Next
USub:
            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & Mid(UpperSub, lngE, 1)

        Case 97 To 122 'Lowercase
            'Find position in alpha string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(LowerAlpha)
                If Mid(LowerAlpha, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo LSub
            Next
LSub:
            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & Mid(LowerSub, lngE, 1)

        Case Else 'Do not substitute

            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & strLetter

    End Select

Next

'Now pass this string through ROT13 for another tier of security

For lngi = 1 To Len(strEncrypt)
    Encrypt = Encrypt & Chr(Asc(Mid(strEncrypt, lngi, 1)) + 13)
Next

End Function
```

And this is the Decryption that goes with it:

```
Public Function Decrypt(strvalue As String) As String

Const LowerAlpha    As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const LowerSub      As String = "zebrascdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy" 'zebras
Const UpperAlpha    As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Const UpperSub      As String = "ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY" 'ZEBRAS

Dim lngi            As Long
Dim lngE            As Long
Dim strDecrypt      As String
Dim strLetter       As String

If strvalue & "" = "" Then Exit Function

'Reverse the ROT13 cipher

For lngi = 1 To Len(strvalue)
    strDecrypt = strDecrypt & Chr(Asc(Mid(strvalue, lngi, 1)) - 13)
Next

'Now reverse the encryption

For lngi = 1 To Len(strDecrypt)

    strLetter = Mid(strDecrypt, lngi, 1)

    Select Case Asc(strLetter)

        Case 65 To 90 'Uppercase
            'Find position in sub string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(UpperSub)
                If Mid(UpperSub, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo USub
            Next
USub:
            Decrypt = Decrypt & Mid(UpperAlpha, lngE, 1)

        Case 97 To 122 'Lowercase
            'Find position in sub string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(LowerSub)
                If Mid(LowerSub, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo LSub
            Next
LSub:
            Decrypt = Decrypt & Mid(LowerAlpha, lngE, 1)

        Case Else 'Do not substitute

            Decrypt = Decrypt & strLetter

    End Select

Next

End Function
```

I hope the coding is very simple to follow for those who do not have vast experience with VBA coding and it can be lifted straight from the page; but again thanks for all the other answers.

Comment: This is very weak (excuse of) an encryption bordering ridiculous. Try something stronger like RC4 that can be implemented in less lines-of-code. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025644/vb6-encrypt-text-using-password

Comment: I appreciate Sub Ciphers are quite old now and not considered the best but I just needed something simple for this case, you got to admit though, this encrypted string looks pretty cool "S€4-XY^-x‚~-zRrur€r|-€pz€-px„-„px-„|-~|zVV†-z~|9-r€-r-=‚~-p=>|" If anyone has any time then give decrypting it a blast, I'd like to see how easy it actually is. : )

Comment: For the purposes I currently have of trying to set up a "login" password encryption and verification this is a lot of extra work versus just storing the hashed value and then validating by computing the input to the same algorithm at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29).  There's a Visual Basic 6 version that will work in Access, available here:

http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoBlowfishVer6.html

You can also try [TwoFish.](http://www.schneier.com/twofish.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple example [here](http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vb6codebank.htm#Encrypt) or you can use the even simpler [ROT13](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=345183) cipher.

These are useful for obscuring a little text, but I'd not use them for anything that actually needs to be kept secure.