# select block of text, right click and change it to something else like *****

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I have some loosely formatted text in a database field. I need a tool (any language even sql will do) to transform certain portions of the field to xxxxx or *****.

e.g. Say the content of the field is - "I am trying to get something done. My Email is sdge@geemail.com. Address is - 123 Mnop Street, New York, NY, 10010. Phone: 1-212-325-0342"

Now, I need a way to change this to - "I am trying to get something done. My Email is sdXX@gXXXXXX.cXX. Address is - 1XX MXXX StXXXX, NXX YXXX, NY, 1XXXX. Phone: 1-XXX-XXX-XXXX"

I'm thinking that since the data is not highly structured, the best way to do this will be on the front end in some editor by using a macro or something like that. The user will select the text they want to distort and right click and say - "Hide" or "Distort" and the selected text will become all Xs.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have a definite data structure, I think you would be better to use 'Reversible Encryption' on the string instead, this old question of mine may help you in the right direction.

[MS Access VBA Substitution Cipher Encrypt/Decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537419/ms-access-vba-substitution-cipher-encrypt-decrypt)

Comment: Thanks for that idea. But, I was looking for something simpler - encryption will be a little too complex for my needs. But, thanks anyway.

Comment: @DineshM Do you mean complex for your users on screen or for you to implement, if the latter then my code can be lifted striaght from the page and works.