# Could this set of VB6 encryption functions be cracked?

Tags: encryption, vb6, cryptography

```
 Public Function EncryptString(theString As String, TheKey As String) As String
    Dim X As Long
    Dim eKey As Byte, eChr As Byte, oChr As Byte, tmp$
    For i = 1 To Len(TheKey)
         'generate a key
          eKey = Asc(Mid$(TheKey, i, 1)) Xor eKey
    Next

    'reset random function
    Rnd -1
    'initilize our key as the random seed
    Randomize eKey
    'generate a pseudo old char
    oChr = Int(Rnd * 256)
    'start encryption
    For X = 1 To Len(theString)
        pp = pp + 1
        If pp > Len(TheKey) Then pp = 1
        eChr = Asc(Mid$(theString, X, 1)) Xor _
                   Int(Rnd * 256) Xor Asc(Mid$(TheKey, pp, 1)) Xor oChr
        tmp$ = tmp$ & Chr(eChr)
        oChr = eChr
    Next
    EncryptString = AsctoHex(tmp$)    

End Function


Public Function DecryptString(theString As String, TheKey As String) As String

Dim X As Long
Dim eKey As Byte, eChr As Byte, oChr As Byte, tmp$
For i = 1 To Len(TheKey)
     'generate a key
     eKey = Asc(Mid$(TheKey, i, 1)) Xor eKey
Next
'reset random function
Rnd -1
'initilize our key as the random seed
Randomize eKey
'generate a pseudo old char
oChr = Int(Rnd * 256)
'start decryption
tmp$ = HexToAsc(theString)
    DecryptString = ""
    For X = 1 To Len(tmp$)
    pp = pp + 1
    If pp > Len(TheKey) Then pp = 1
    If X > 1 Then oChr = Asc(Mid$(tmp$, X - 1, 1))
    eChr = Asc(Mid$(tmp$, X, 1)) Xor Int(Rnd * 256) Xor _
           Asc(Mid$(TheKey, pp, 1)) Xor oChr
        DecryptString = DecryptString & Chr$(eChr)
Next

End Function


Private Function AsctoHex(ByVal astr As String)

For X = 1 To Len(astr)
hc = Hex$(Asc(Mid$(astr, X, 1)))
nstr = nstr & String(2 - Len(hc), "0") & hc
Next
AsctoHex = nstr

End Function
```

Comment: "Yes", by definition. You're not smarter than the hackers.

Comment: Use the available MS Crypto APIs

Comment: @tcarvin: are these part of Win7/Win8?

Comment: There is no system can be created that cannot be beaten, it's the nature of "if you can think of it, so can they". I would re-think whether encryption is essential, if so and if you need a simple example that is reversible then check out one of my old questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537419/ms-access-vba-substitution-cipher-encrypt-decrypt as you can see it's simple, although no one has taken on the challenge of posting the decrytped string ^_^

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't ever try to implement encryption like this yourself. It is very hard to do correctly, and very easy to accidentally build in vulnerabilities.

It would be much easier and safer to find an existing solution that has been proven to work and vastly tested. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821762) is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of flaws in this:

You will run into trouble, if you want to decrypt on a different system than where you encrypted (or if you update your system, ...): `Randomize eKey` with a following set of calls to `Rnd` is not guaranteed to return the same sequence after reboot. It definitly will NOT return the same sequence on different systems.

You reduce the password to a single 8-bit value (eKey), so your encryption has a factual key length  of 8 bits.

In Short: Whoever has access to a system similar enough to yours (i.e. a system, where your decryption would actually produce the cleartext) just needs to clone your `DecryptString` function and run it with eKey=0..255.

**Forget it, use something that works. Read [Schneier on homebrew encryption](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html).**

Comment: I was worried about the `Rnd` being different but I think VB6 generates the same set of numbers everytime the generator is reset with `Rnd -1` ?

Comment: I agree that would defeat the purpose of using `Rnd` but it is not my code.