# Convert VB6 code to PHP

Tags: php, vb6

I want to convert `Visual Basic 6` Code to PHP Code. I am new to PHP please help me to convert my `VB6` Code to `PHP`. So far I tried to convert this into php code when I tried the code there is an error in the "

> CryptRC4 = CryptRC4 & Chr$((pvCryptXor(baS((CLng(baS(li)) + baS(lJ)) Mod 256), Asc(Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1)))));

part and also I don't know how to proceed to the sub functions. Please see the codes below. The vb code is used to `encrypt` strings. I want to convert it to php format.

PHP Code

```
<?php 

    function CryptRC4($sText,$sKey){
        $baS = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                          16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
                          32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,
                          48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,
                          64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
                          80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,
                          96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,
                          112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,
                          128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,
                          144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,
                          160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,
                          176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,
                          192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,
                          208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,
                          224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,
                          240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255);
        $baK = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                          16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
                          32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,
                          48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,
                          64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,
                          80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,
                          96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,
                          112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,
                          128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,
                          144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,
                          160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,
                          176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,
                          192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,
                          208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,
                          224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,
                          240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255);
        $bytSwap = 0;
        $li = 0;
        $lJ = 0;
        $lIdx = 0;

        for( $lIdx = 0; $lIdx < 256; $lIdx++){
            $baS[$lIdx] = $lIdx;
            $baK[$lIdx] = ord(substr($sKey, 1 + ($lIdx % strlen($sKey)), 1));   
        }

        for($li = 0; $li < 256; $li++){
            $lJ = ($baS[$li] + $baK[$li]) % 256;
            $bytSwap = $baS[$li];
            $baS[$li] = $baS[$lJ];
            $baS[$lJ] = $bytSwap;
        }

        $li = 0;
        $lJ = 0;
        $data_str = "";
        for($lIdx = 0; $lIdx < strlen($sText); $lIdx++){
            $li = ($li + 1) % 256;
            $lJ = ($lJ + $baS[$li]) % 256;
            $bytSwap = $baS[$li];
            $baS[$li] = $baS[$lJ];
            $baS[$lJ] = $bytSwap;
            #echo chr((pvCryptXor($baS[(round(($baS[$li]) + $baS[$lJ])) % 256], ord(substr($sText, $lIdx, 1)))));
            $data_str .= chr((pvCryptXor($baS[(round(($baS[$li]) + $baS[$lJ])) % 256], ord(substr($sText, $lIdx, 1)))));
        }   
        echo $data_str;
    }


        function pvCryptXor($li, $lJ){
            if($li = $lJ){
                $pcx = $lJ;
            }
            else {
                $pcx = $li Xor $lJ;
            }

            return $pcx;
        }

        unction ToHexDump($sText) {
    $lIdx;
    for($lIdx = 1; $lIdx < strlen($sText); $lIdx++){
        $thd .= Right$("0" & Hex(Asc(Mid(sText, lIdx, 1))), 2)
        echo $thd;
    }
    return $thd;
}

FromHexDump("events");

function FromHexDump($sText) {
    $fhd = "";
    for($lIdx = 0; $lIdx < strlen($sText); $lIdx++){
         $fhd .= chr(CLng("&H" & Mid(sText, lIdx, 2)));
    }
    return $fhd;
}

    ?>
```

VB Code:

```
Public Function CryptRC4(sText As String, sKey As String) As String
On Error Resume Next
    Dim baS(0 To 255) As Byte
    Dim baK(0 To 255) As Byte
    Dim bytSwap     As Byte
    Dim li          As Long
    Dim lJ          As Long
    Dim lIdx        As Long

    For lIdx = 0 To 255
        baS(lIdx) = lIdx
        baK(lIdx) = Asc(Mid$(sKey, 1 + (lIdx Mod Len(sKey)), 1))
    Next
    For li = 0 To 255
        lJ = (lJ + baS(li) + baK(li)) Mod 256
        bytSwap = baS(li)
        baS(li) = baS(lJ)
        baS(lJ) = bytSwap
    Next
    li = 0
    lJ = 0
    For lIdx = 1 To Len(sText)
        li = (li + 1) Mod 256
        lJ = (lJ + baS(li)) Mod 256
        bytSwap = baS(li)
        baS(li) = baS(lJ)
        baS(lJ) = bytSwap
        CryptRC4 = CryptRC4 & Chr$((pvCryptXor(baS((CLng(baS(li)) + baS(lJ)) Mod 256), Asc(Mid$(sText, lIdx, 1)))))
    Next
End Function

Private Function pvCryptXor(ByVal li As Long, ByVal lJ As Long) As Long
On Error Resume Next
    If li = lJ Then
        pvCryptXor = lJ
    Else
        pvCryptXor = li Xor lJ
    End If
End Function

Public Function ToHexDump(sText As String) As String
On Error Resume Next
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    For lIdx = 1 To Len(sText)
        ToHexDump = ToHexDump & Right$("0" & Hex(Asc(Mid(sText, lIdx, 1))), 2)
    Next
End Function

Public Function FromHexDump(sText As String) As String
On Error Resume Next
    Dim lIdx            As Long

    For lIdx = 1 To Len(sText) Step 2
        FromHexDump = FromHexDump & Chr$(CLng("&H" & Mid(sText, lIdx, 2)))
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I revised your updated code and it seems you only had a few minor errors in it, look and my changes:

I guess you can use the build in PHP function `hex2bin` and `bin2hex` instead fo you own hex conversion.

```
function CryptRC4($sText,$sKey){
    $baS = range(0, 255); // you can use range instead of your manual arrays
    $baK = range(0, 255);
    $bytSwap = 0;
    $li = 0;
    $lJ = 0;
    $lIdx = 0;

    for( $lIdx = 0; $lIdx < 256; $lIdx++){
        $baS[$lIdx] = $lIdx;
        $baK[$lIdx] = ord(substr($sKey, 1 + ($lIdx % strlen($sKey)), 1));
    }

    for($li = 0; $li < 256; $li++){
        $lJ = ($baS[$li] + $baK[$li]) % 256;
        $bytSwap = $baS[$li];
        $baS[$li] = $baS[$lJ];
        $baS[$lJ] = $bytSwap;
    }

    $li = 0;
    $lJ = 0;
    $data_str = "";
    for($lIdx = 0; $lIdx < strlen($sText); $lIdx++){
        $li = ($li + 1) % 256;
        $lJ = ($lJ + $baS[$li]) % 256;
        $bytSwap = $baS[$li];
        $baS[$li] = $baS[$lJ];
        $baS[$lJ] = $bytSwap;
        #echo chr((pvCryptXor($baS[(round(($baS[$li]) + $baS[$lJ])) % 256], ord(substr($sText, $lIdx, 1)))));
        $data_str .= chr((pvCryptXor($baS[(round(($baS[$li]) + $baS[$lJ])) % 256], ord(substr($sText, $lIdx, 1)))));
    }
    return $data_str; // changed from echo to return
}

function pvCryptXor($li, $lJ){
    if($li == $lJ){ // you had an error here, use == to compare instead of a single =
        $pcx = $lJ;
    }
    else {
        $pcx = $li ^ $lJ; // XOR function in PHP is the ^ operator
    }

    return $pcx;
}


$str_hex = bin2hex("events");
$str_enc = CryptRC4($str_hex,"password");
$str_dec = hex2bin(CryptRC4($str_enc,"password"));

echo $str_hex . PHP_EOL . $str_enc . PHP_EOL . $str_dec;
```

OUTPUT:

> 6576656e7473
>
> '�����~i��
>
> events

So it seems to me as it's actually encoding and decoding correctly!?

Comment: Don't answer questions like this. OP has not even tried.

Comment: how about FromHexDump($sText) and ToHexDump($sText)?  the code when i encrypt is CryptRC4(FromHexDump("events"), "password")); please see the updated code above with the fromhexdump function

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know at first, but with the update he provided almost the complete code with some errors..

Comment: @xander oh didn't see that.

Comment: @MaricrisPacheco You don't need those function for the RC4 encryption, but let me see what I can do.

Comment: @xander I need that sir, so that the encryption is only accepting letters and numbers

Comment: Updated with build in PHP function `hex2bin` and `bin2hex`, I think you don't need your own `ToHexDump` and `FromHexDump`!?

Comment: @xander the data is still different sir. I really need the tohexdump and fromhexdump functions those functions are essential for the encryption. I dont know how to convert those two functions into php code

Comment: @xander please see updated code for tohexdump and fromhexdump

Comment: Yes there are still errors in your code, VB6 `&` is a `.` in PHP (string concatenation), and you just need to replace the VB6 functions like `Mid` to PHP function like you have before. But I don't see a reason why you would want that? Your `ToHexDump` just converts a string to hex, exactely what the PHP function `bin2hex` does, only faster and better, it can handly multi byte chars, your function will fail for those special cases for example. `bin2hex` is also padding with `0` same as your function does, e.g. `bin2hex("\n")` becomes `0a`.

Comment: @xander: great job! IMHO, questions about how to port VB6 legacy code to PHP shouldn't be deprecated too much. I feel not all people want agree that old VB shall be migrated just only to .NET.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the original VB6 implementation of `CryptRC4` function is from my [answer to "VB6 encrypt text using password" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064669/40691) on SO.

So let me try answering your Q with this short `php` implementation of all public functions in the VB6 snippet:

```
function CryptRC4($text, $key) {
    return openssl_encrypt($text, "RC4-40", $key, 1 | 2);
}

function ToHexDump($text) {
    return strtoupper(bin2hex($text));
}

function FromHexDump($text) {
    return hex2bin($text);
}
```

You can excercise these one-liners with something like this:

```
$text = "a message here";
$password = "password";
$encr = ToHexDump(CryptRC4($text, $password));
$decr = CryptRC4(FromHexDump($encr), $password);
echo $text . PHP_EOL . $encr . PHP_EOL . $decr;
```

Comment: mcrypt_encrypt is depricated

Comment: For newer php version you can try `openssl_encrypt($text, "RC4-40", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING)`, you should really learn how to do your own research, it took only 1 minute to find that alternative for you..

Comment: @xander i knew that but i really need to convert my code to php so that i can decrypt password inside my database

Comment: @MaricrisPacheco I'm not actively using `php` but still can understand what @xander is telling me. Check out the new impl of `CryptRC4` above. Which "my code" do you refer to? The one from my answer I linked above?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

As it's intended for passwords, you can save yourself a lot of hassle. PHP has got built in functions (version 5.5 and newer) that are designed for dealing with the hashing of passwords and for verifying hashed passwords against the password submitted by a user. Have a read through the PHP relevant PHP manual pages http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php

Comment: yes i read that but my clients are using that vb function in order to login if i use hashing and de hashing their passwords will not work that is why I need to convert my vb code to php